# Is "including in the Neckar" acting as a modifier in the given sentence? If so, what is it modifying?

Tags: modifiers

> He hoped to compete in some challenging open-water events later in the summer, ***including in the Neckar***.

Is "*including in the Neckar*" acting as a modifier in the sentence above? If so, what is it modifying?

Comment: It's adverbial, modifying "compete in some challenging open-water events later in the summer". You could argue "including" is functioning as a preposition. Do you have some confusion about the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: @StuartF Thanks. How is "including in the Neckar" modifying "compete in ..."?

Comment: Dropping the third 'in' would be more idiomatic.

Comment: The sentence is similar to "He will compete in ABC--and compete in C especially." The Neckar seems to be one open-water event being singled out as special to him.

Comment: Note that _events_ has been deleted from the phrase _including **events** in the Neckar_.

Comment: No: it's a preposition phrase functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Supplements are not modifiers, but loosely attached elements providing supplementary non-integrated content.

Answer (score 1):

It acts like an adverb:

> Adverbials are words that we use to give more information about a verb.

In this case it modifies:

> compete in some challenging open-water events later in the summer

Comment: isn't the verb "hoped" in this sentence

Comment: *He hoped* is outside of the issue of the Neckar phrase.

Answer (score 0):

> including in the Neckar.

is a **free modifier**: it modifies the whole main clause.

Free modifiers are in contrast to bound modifiers which modify a word or phrase.

https://www.thoughtco.com/free-modifier-grammar-1690807